# Writing XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm using a piece of code for writing a XML file (using LINQ)(was using XMLWriter and code was getting too dirty, LINQ is cleaner and seems to be faster).

The question is: It writes the XML but only the first part of it - i have other statements inside an if who aren't being written.

I set some breakpoints where the if happens and found that everything is happening there as it should be (variables are getting their values, etc) - only the XML isn't writing.

On the first part of the code you may notice many closing parentheses - without 'em i can't get the XML to work - or, if i try to change their order (like closing sooner) when trying to convert it says XML will be on a invalid format.

```
    private void openXMLToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentcolor;
        XElement xmldoc = new XElement("JMF",
            new XAttribute("SenderID", "InkZone-Controller"),
            new XAttribute("version", "1.2"),
        //new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1"),

        new XElement("Command",
        new XAttribute("ID", "cmd.00695"),
        new XAttribute("Type", "Resource"),
        new XElement("ResourceCmdParams",
        new XAttribute("Resourcename", "InkZoneProfile"),
        new XAttribute("JobID", "K_41")),

        new XElement("InkZoneProfile",
        new XAttribute("ID", "r0013"),
        new XAttribute("Class", "Parameter"),
        new XAttribute("Locked", "False"),
        new XAttribute("Status", "Available"),
        new XAttribute("PartIDKeys", "SignatureName SheetName Side Separation"),
        new XAttribute("DescriptiveName", "Schieberwerte von DI"),
        new XAttribute("ZoneWidth", "32")),

        new XElement("InkZoneProfile",
        new XAttribute("SignatureName", "SIG1")),

        new XElement("InkzoneProfile",
        new XAttribute("Locked", "False"),
        new XAttribute("Sheetname", "S1")),

        new XElement("InkZoneProfile",
        new XAttribute("Side", "Front")),

                //Loop for getting black values and store them on XML
                    for(int i=0; i<stringsize; i++)
                        {
                            currentcolor = colors[i];
                            if(currentcolor == "Black")
                                {
                                    //Extracting numbers from blackzones
                                    Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"HDMInkB \[(.*?)\]",
                                        RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                                    var v1 = regex1.Match(hdmzones);
                                    string blackzones = v1.Groups[1].ToString();
                                    //Converting to string - add a delimiter into each space
                                    blackzones = Regex.Replace(blackzones, @"\s+", "|");
                                    Double[] numbers; //An array of Doubles - store numbers separated
                                    string[] numbers_str = blackzones.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                    numbers = new Double[numbers_str.Length];
                                    //Loop trough numbers
                                        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
                                        {
                                            numbers[j] = Double.Parse(numbers_str[j], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                            //Converts each number on the string to a Double number, store it in a position
                                            //in the Double array
                                            numbers[j] = numbers[j] / 100; //Needed calculus
                                            numbers[j] = Math.Round(numbers[j], 3); //Storing numbers rounded
                                        }
                                    string blackvalues = String.Join(" ", numbers.Select(f => f.ToString()));
                //Converting values back to string - so i can insert on the XML without problems
                new XElement("InkZoneProfile",
                    new XAttribute("Separation", currentcolor),
                    new XAttribute("ZoneSettingsX", blackvalues));


            }//Closing BLACK if Statement

                        }//Closing for statement for XMLAttribute
                                //Saving XML Document
                                string strPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                                 System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);

                                string path2 = "new_xml.xml";
                                string combined = Path.Combine(strPath, path2);
                                xmldoc.Save(combined);


    }//Closing ConvertXML
```

Comment: Consider indenting _everything_ properly, your code, the element definition, everything. Not only will it be easier to read, but it'll also be easier to spot any potential issues in how it's set up.

Comment: First of all, XDocument cannot be faster than XmlWriter because XmlWriter does stream-based writing of XML data while XDocument builds XML data as an object model in memory.

Comment: Can't have a for loop in an object declaration/constructor, e.g. `new XElement("blah", for (int i....`

Comment: I try to ident. Visual Studio Seems to screw my identation evereytime. I'm planning to rewrite the entire code as soon i get it done. Also, its missing variables because i posted only the XML part (didn't want to post a big code).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems missing parts. As it is, I don't think it could even compile. Indentation is incoherent and some of the variables aren't even defined, so it's hard to see where your problem actually lies.

Nevertheless, I think I may know a trick to help you get your elements in order. You may use a separate private method to yield all the elements you want according to a given list of colors.

```
private IEnumerable<XElement> GetBlackvaluesElements(string hdmzones, params string[] colors)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
    {
        currentColor = color[i];
        if (currentColor = "Black")
        {
            /* Regex, Calculus & other stuff to get string blackvalues here */
            yield return new XElement("InkZoneProfile",
                new XAttribute("Separation", currentColor),
                new XAttribute("ZoneSettingsX", blackvalues));
        }
    }
}

private void OpenXMLToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var commandElement = new XElement("Command");
    /* Add hardcoded elements to commandElement here */
    // Adding blackvalues to commandElement
    commandElement.Add(GetBlackvaluesElements(hdmzones, colors).ToArray());

    var xmldoc = new XElement("JMF",
        /* add required attributes here */
        commandElement);

    /* Save document here */
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks your your reply & help.

Comment: i've changed everything to xmlwriter - getting another kind of error, will post it in another questions. Thanks.